# Proving nonexistence of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am attempting to show that there is not a function $h$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{C}$ where $h(x)=\frac{2}{3}$ for all large $k\in\mathbb{N}$. My idea is to consider $g=\frac{1}{h}$ and use max modulus principle because there is a sequence of points in its domain taking $g$ to infinity. However, I suspect that I am underusing the fact that the argument is phrased in a strange way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $k \to \infty$ we get $h(0)=0$. Let $m$ be the order of $0$ of $h$ at $0$. Then $\frac {h(z)} {z^{m}}$ tends to a finite non-zero limit as $z \to 0$. In particular, $k^{2m} h(\frac 1 {k^{2}})$ tends to a finite non-zero limit as $k \to \infty$. Use the expression for $h(\frac 1 {k^{2}})$ to get a  contardiction. [You will get $2m=3$ which is impossible].

Comment: Thanks! But is it implied from the statement of the question that $h$ is defined at 0? Does this change things?

Comment: It is clearly stated that $h$ is defined in a neighborhood of $0$. @user5684138

Comment: I wasn't sure if this meant "deleted" neighborhood.

Comment: No. If it is a deleted neighborhood they would state it explicitly.  @user5684138

Comment: If it is a deleted neighborhood then such a  function does exist. @user5684138

Comment: But where did $h(0)=0$ come from?

Comment: @TedShifrin h is holomorphic so it is continuous. We are given a sequence heading toward zero where it holds that h is also heading toward zero.